# Dataset of retraction fines per publisher

Tags: publications, reference-request, publishers, fees, retraction

I read in the Nature comment [Reproducibility: A tragedy of errors](http://www.nature.com/news/reproducibility-a-tragedy-of-errors-1.19264) authored by David B. Allison, Andrew W. Brown, Brandon J. George& Kathryn A. Kaiser and published today

> Science relies essentially but complacently on self-correction, yet scientific publishing raises severe disincentives against such correction. **One publisher states that it will charge the author who initiates withdrawal of a published paper US$10,000.**

(This Nature comment uses the term withdrawal in lieu of retraction)

Is there any dataset that lists retraction fines per publisher?

Comment: What is "withdrawal of a published paper"? Do you mean retraction? Usually withdrawal refers to withdrawing a paper before it is published. What kind of withdrawal are *you* referring to in your question?

Comment: @ff524 Thanks, good point, yes retraction. (I believe this Nature comment use withdrawal in lieu of retraction)

Comment: It is very unlikely somebody went to the aggravation of finding out... and it could very well change drastically over time, be different e.g. for a special topic issue, ...

Comment: @vonbrand I'm sure this is the kind of data http://retractionwatch.com/ would be interested to compile, amongst other organizations and researchers.